# How to end the fixed element using the .offset.top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the Javascript code `.offset.top` to fix an element, but I want to end it when reaching another element.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (){
        var sidebartop = $('.single-content').offset().top;
        $(window).scroll(function (event){
            var y = $(this).scrollTop();
            if ( y>= sidebartop ){
                $('#sharing-links').addClass('fixed');
            } else {
                $('#sharing-links').removeClass('fixed');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

this is the html

```
    <div id="sharing-links">
    <!-- this is the fixed element -->
</div>
<div class="single-content">
    <!-- when the div reaches here is adds the .fixed -->
    <div class="div2">
        <!-- I want the fixed element to end when it reaches this div -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: share your html and css code as well

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of related questions about this subject, you will find a lot of tricks, some works, others not so well, but when is about scroll to fixed, I **always use this jquery plugin**, created to solve this exact problem.

#### Demos:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZczEt/167/
http://jsfiddle.net/y3qV5/434/
http://jsfiddle.net/k2R3G/81/

#### Plugin and source

https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed

#### Usage:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mydiv').scrollToFixed();
});
```

### EDIT:

If you are just looking for that line, you should use this to calculate the `.single-content` top.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var auxtop = $('.single-content').offset().top 
    var margintop = parseFloat($('.single-content').css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
    var sidebartop = auxtop - margintop;
    $(window).scroll(function (event){
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();
        if ( y>= sidebartop ){
            $('#sharing-links').addClass('fixed');
        } else {
            $('#sharing-links').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I am not that good with javascript. I just need the line where the fixed div will end

Comment: thanks the var are so reasonable, but can you provide the function too